# What would the the most appropriate layout for a sniper in a Close Quarters map?

Tags: battlefield-3

[Battlefield 3] 
I'm looking for the best sniper in a close quarters map. Based on stats, it has to be fairly accurate from being fired by the hip(laser sight can be attached) while dealing a decent amount of damage. (2 shot kill, under a second)

I was thinking of possibly the SKS with a red dot sight + laser. The QBU-88(Hope I spelled that right) and M417 also look interesting however I don't know if they deal a decent amount of damage along with a good rate of fire.

The JNG-90 also looks like a decent rifle, however I don't know if it would be good for a close quarters scenario.

I'm referring to the Battlefield 3 Close Quarters DLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are extremely accurate, a bolt-action rifle (like the JNG-90) will not suffice for close quarters. You will need a semi-auto rifle. There are two "levels" of semi-auto rifles - the QBU-88, M110, M39, and SVD, which all deal 50 damage at close range (enough for a two-hit kill or 1-hit headshot) with 10-round magazines and 260 rpm rates of fire (the M39 has a 300 rpm). The M417 and SKS have 20-round magazines with slightly higher  rates of fire (295 for the M417, 333 for the SKS), but they have higher recoil numbers and slightly less accuracy. Also, the SKS only deals 43 damage at close range, requiring a headshot for a 2-shot kill.

The guns all behave slightly differently, so I would recommend trying out the weapons first to get your own opinion, as many different players I play with prefer different weapons. You can take a look at the source charts [here](http://symthic.com/charts.php?class=4&sort=Class&adsc=ASC&attc=-), but my recommendation would be the M39 EMR, as it provides good rof, damage, and accuracy.